# Dispatch private class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a dispatch table to dispatch private class methods. My code looks like this:

```py
class Snackmachine:
    __dispatch = {
        'login': __login,
        'logout': __logout,
        'addAccount': __add_user,
        'deposit': __deposit,
        'balance': __balance,
        'products': __print_products,
        'buy': __buy_product,
        'exit': __exit_program,
        'restock': __restock,
        'addProduct': __add_product
    }

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def __login(self):
        ...
    def __logout(self):
        ...
    def __add_user(self):
        ...
    def __deposit(self):
        ...
    def __balance(self):
        ...
    def __print_products(self):
        ...
    def __buy_product(self):
        ...
    def __exit_program(self):
        ...
    def __restock(self):
        ...
    def __add_product(self):
        ...

    def __command_dispatch(self, command):
        '''Invokes console commands with dispatch table'''
        try:
            self.__dispatch[command]()

        except KeyError:
            _print_fail("## Unknown Command!")
```

But using this code I get the error: `NameError: name '_Snackmachine__login' is not defined`

I tried using

```py
bound = self.__dispatch[command].__get__(self, type(self))
bound()
```

which was suggested in another StackOverflow question, but it gave me the exact same error.

I thought it has something to do with the private modifier, but when changing *__login()* to *login()* I still get a name error.

So why does the name error occur and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: None of those methods *exist* at the point where you're trying to build the table.

Comment: **Python doesn't have private methods**. There *are not access modifiers in Python*

Comment: Anyway, this works like anything else in python, you cannot use a name before it is defined. You dont define the functions before you try to create your `dict`. Put the dict after the functions have been defined. Also, you really should stop using double-underscore name-mangling like this. Use a *single* underscore to signal that an attribute or method is not part of the public api

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something stupid like that. I really should stop coding at 3am.

@juanpa.arrivillaga I didn't used to do the double underscore thing until my professor adviced us to use them to mark private methods and attributes. And as I understood correctly Python changes method names with two underscores to make it harder to access them from outside. Or won't it?

Comment: @DomeE__ double-underscore name-mangling is only to prevent *accidental* name-colllisions in subclasses. It is **not the same thing as private**. Python *doesn't have private*